# Android: My app is not supporting Galxy S 4

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm trying to update my application on the store to make it compatible with the Galaxy S 4.

My app uses Maps V2, it must not be installed on tablets, has minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion both set to 9.

This is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it...."
    android:versionCode="113"
    android:versionName="1.1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <permission
        android:name="it....permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="small" />

        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="normal" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="..." >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            ...
            List of all the activities
            ...
        </activity>

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIz  ...  j-Y" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does someone knows why the Galaxy S 4 is not supported when i try to upload my application on the store?

This is what i getwhen I look at the compatible devices of my new APK in the Android Developer Console:

[image]

P.S. In the "screenDensity" attribute for the "screen" tag I have to use the value "480" instead of "xxhdpi" because it is not supported.

That's the error I get if I use "xxhdpi":

> Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value
>   'xxhdpi').    AndroidManifest.xml /ICSMob line 84 Android AAPT Problem

P.P.S. the xxhdpi screen is supported: I can see it when I click on the APK line in the Dev Console and expand the screen layout section. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: s4 is xxhdpi a newly introduced one 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Edit Target SDK version to 17 in manifest

```
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

Comment: I've just uploaded a new version on the store with the target version as you suggested. The Galaxy S 4 was in the list of compatible devices. I'm waiting for the update to go through and as soon as I will see my app installed on a GS4 I will accept your answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Galaxy S IV uses `xxhdpi` asset, so this is the reason, why SIV is not supported in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Galaxy S4 is a `xxhdpi` device.

Try adding this also to the compatible screens tag

```
<screen
        android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Comment: Sorry I have to down-vote your answer because xxhdpi is not allowed at all. Information from Google: Note: This attribute currently does not accept xxhdpi as a valid value, but you can instead specify 480 as the value, which is the approximate threshold for xhdpi screens.