# Android - Play Store Unsupported Device

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

My App manifest is as described below. I've mentioned all the required flag to false below..

FYI : I've added permission for Amazon maps as its Universal between Amazon and Play store.
Current application is having **337 Unsupported Devices** on Market.
Some of them are

---

Samsungolleh– ik1
 SamsungGalaxy– gt-i7500
 SamsungHomesync– spcwifi
 SamsungMoment– sph-m900
 SamsungGT-I5800L– GT-I5800L
 SamsungMoment– SPH-M900
 SamsungBehold II– sgh-t939
 SamsungGalaxy Star– mintss
 SamsungGalaxy Player 50– YP-G50
 SamsungEuropa– GT-I5500M
 SamsungGalaxy 070– hendrix
 SamsungGalaxy Star– mint
 SamsungBehold II– SGH_T939
 SamsungSpica– spica
 SamsungGalaxy Spica

and many others..

---

Am I missing anything in AndroidManifest.xml ?

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vishal"
    android:versionCode="35"
    android:versionName="3.2.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<!-- GOOGLE MAP API V2 -->
<permission
    android:name="com.vishal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.vishal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- GOOGLE MAP API V2 -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- To Get GPS Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- To Get GPS Location -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- To Call Salon -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- To Call Salon -->


<!-- To Capture from Camera -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- To Capture from Camera -->


<!-- PUSH NOTIFICATION PERMISSIONS -->    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="com.vishal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.vishal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- PUSH NOTIFICATION PERMISSIONS -->

<!-- CALENDAR PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

<application
    android:name="TestApplication"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="KEY DESCRIBED HERE" />

    <!--
        All Activity Tags are mentioned here
    -->

    <amazon:enable-feature
        android:name="com.amazon.geo.maps"
        android:required="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.vishal" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>       
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

Comment: try with android:targetSdkVersion="17"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673640/android-my-app-is-not-supporting-galxy-s-4/17738629#17738629

Comment: Looks to all very old phones which probably just are below API 8

Comment: What's the actual problem, a certain device is not supported on the PlayStore - if yes, then which one? You're limiting the API's on the phones between 8 and 10 - that's very few of the total.

Comment: @g00dy still its supporting S4 and S3.. so that might not be the case

Comment: @Vishal Khakhkhar - yes, but the minimum is set to 8, if a device is below that, there's no way that you can support it. Put the minSDK to "5" and see if your code is compatible with that.

Comment: @g00dy yes accept it'll not support below 8.. but target 10 should not restrict above or equal 10.

Comment: @Vishal Khakhkhar - Agreed, I meant to write 8 to 17, but the "edit" dissapeared by that time. Check the not supported device's API level by default and see if it's outside the minSDK ="8"

Answer (score 1):

this can be various causes but a quick research it can be the minimum required API level. For instance I did a search on the following phone:

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i5700_galaxy_spica-2965.php

This has max 2.1 that is API 7 and not 8. It can also be a combination of permissions. So clear all not needed permissions etc... To target all devices compatibility can be very difficult to achieve.