# how to make my application supported tablets in android?

Tags: android, device

My application have `minSdkVersion="8"` & `targetSdkVersion="9"`.

Also added

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
```

in manifest file. And i did not use `<support-screens>` in my application's manifest. Because I think it is true by default.

While downloading this application from android market using `Samsung Galaxy tab GT-P1000` (Android OS 2.2) it works  fine, but when downloading using `Penta Tab IS709C` (Android OS 4.0.4) this shows 
'App not compatible with this application' error.

What is the issue here. How can I make my application have support for all phones and tablets?

Comment: your `targetSdkVersion="9"`.

Comment: What's your maxSDK in the Manifest?

Comment: What is meant by targetSdkVersion? I did not get it. How can i specify targetSdkVersion for applications?

Comment: Did not specify maxSDK  in my manifest yet.

Comment: Your `android:maxSdkVersion` must be bigger or equal to 15 in order to support Android OS 4.0.4. -> see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: @AshaSoman http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html. also check the warning. it says not recommended to use `android:maxSdkVersion`

Comment: look at this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673640/android-my-app-is-not-supporting-galxy-s-4/17738629#17738629

Comment: As @Raghunandan already said - that's really the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set **maxSDKVersion**, it is not a good practice.

just change your target SDK

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```