# My application does not support Penta tab

Tags: device, android-support-library, android

I am trying to download my application from android market for Penta IS709C Tablet(480x764,120dpi,4.0.4). My application did not support this tab.But it supports other device including Galaxy s4 and tablets. Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

What is the reason for this strange behavior?Also,I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673640/android-my-app-is-not-supporting-galxy-s-4/17738629#17738629). If it is due to `targetSdkVersion` ,then how is supports Galaxy S4(4.2.2) device?

Comment: Do you have anything in the `<uses-library>` element? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html

Comment: No.I posted manifest with my question.

Comment: I know, but you left some stuff out. It's possible you left this out too, I've seen it happen. Just trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

These two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Imply the device requires `android.hardware.location.network`, `android.hardware.location.gps` *and* `android.hardware.location`

To specify that this is not required, add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

You may like to look through that list more closely to see if any other of your permissions implies a required feature that the Penta IS709C does not have.

Comment: Thanks - my answer remains the same.